# Android starting new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a strange problem in my android application. I am starting one activity from another and the starting code is right, I know it. It works about one or two times of the four launches. Reason, because it is failing that when the second activity is starting, suddenly starting the first and I don't know why, because I don't call this activity. The second activity is exactly right. Can anyone give me some reason of calling the first activity again?
I will not show code, because it too big. I can show parts, that will be interesting for you, if anybody asks it. Thanks a lot and sorry for my english. I really need your help

Activity launching:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("id", ids.get(2));
b.putString("auth", auths.get(2));
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileLoaderActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity is right because it works well, when I call it from another activities

Comment: Provide the code that is used to launch the second activity as well as the `onCreate()` for the second activity.

Comment: Can you copy any exceptions/errors from logcat. You really need to provide more information.

Comment: Exceptions are not important because they are just a result of that problev, but not a reason

Comment: Are you out of your mind? One of the principal purposes of the exception is to identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: Are the ids and auth both a list of strings?

Comment: I mean not all exceptions but current exception, because it doesn,t explain why first activity is started

Comment: It does if it explains the reason why the second activity is crashing or being destroyed and the thus the task is falling back to the next activity on the stack.

Comment: Yes they are and it is exactly right because it works in other activities

Comment: No, it only explains why crashing first activity, but not second

Comment: In that case your question is misleading because it implies the second activity isn't working and the first is. Please re-write the question with further details, add the exception anyway because it might help (you never know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limited possibilities about what might actually be happening.

A possibility if with the first activity at the top of the activity stack, you launch the second activity which crashes on start up, that activity is then destroyed/dies revealing the original activity.

Other possibilities are you are unintentionally calling the wrong activity or that the first activity is getting called from another component altogether.

You can try pressing the back button when then first activity incorrectly is present, if the second activity is present when you press back you know that the second activity was launched and that something somewhere is calling on the first activity again. You could then look at the intent that was calling it for further information. If the second activity isn't present you are either calling the wrong activity from the off or you second activity isn't being created correctly.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I have added to comments/requests for the question to the comments section, what's remaining provides an answer with possible value to the question and thus I don't think warrants being moved.

Comment: But why sometimes it doesn't crashing?

Comment: Really?? you down mark the answer and not the question, when the answer provides probably the most likely reason given the very vague description of the behavior. You also don't provide reason for down marking and should be aware that we are in the process of working through the problem (refining the question then the answer). Not sure you fully grasp the concept of this site, or your just a bit of a bitch.

Comment: @llya Zorin it's ok I don't know who did and it doesn't really matter, I just hope the person who did down mark reads it and learns something.